# Spring raw query parameters in Criteria condition

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-jdbc

I would like to bind in Criteria raw sql condition, like functions BINARY(...) or CAST(...). But i can't find any solution for this case.

I have those code

```
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.query.Criteria;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var criteria = Criteria.where("m.originator").is("BINARY('test')");
        System.out.println(criteria);//m.originator = 'BINARY('test')'
    }
}
```

When i unwrap this condition, it is looks like

`m.originator = 'BINARY('test')'` but i want `m.originator = BINARY('test')` without quotes

How i can do this?